# Can't see imported images using android drawable importer

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-drawable-importer

I'm using [android drawable importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) plugin to import an image. But whenever I select an image it doesn't appear in my drawable directory.

This is the steps I'm taking:

**1)**
[image]

**2)**
[image]

**3)**
[image]

**4)**
In this step it shows the right image name and path.
[image]

**5)**
In this step, it shows importing images loader at the bottom but I see no image in my drawables directory after it has finished.
[image]

**6)**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution but it isn't using android drawable importer. I used an online [tool](https://www.img-bak.in/). It converted my image to respective resolutions and then I manually copied and pasted the converted images to respective directories in res/drawable folder. I'm still keen to know whats wrong with importing images from android drawable importer.

Thanks.

Comment: The online tool doesn't work well with different icon types.